# Not able to run the code on Github : NPM Install and JSON package

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to run the code present on the Github using the npm install

But when I am running the code it says that Error in installing npm modules and hence can't run the code.

I also asked this question to npm forum but they said that it is not based on NPM and hence they can't help. I am a newbee and is learning.

The link to the GItHub is

**https://github.com/Operational-Transformation/ot.js/**

I simply extracted the zip file and tried to run this code using Command Prompt. I want to somehow run this code. Please suggest me method to run this code.

I have Node.js along with socket.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
npm install ot
```

This will install the node package you linked to on github.

You can see the name of the package in the [package.json](https://github.com/Operational-Transformation/ot.js/blob/master/package.json#L2) file

```json
// package.json
{
  "name": "ot",
  "description": "Collaborative editing using operational transformation",
  // ...
```